# Vague deprecation error when running ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, configuration-management, logrotate

My playbook contains vars that are passed to a role. When I run it, I get `[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined Error, in the future this will be a fatal error..`

Here's what I have:

```
---

- hosts: hadoopL0X
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  vars:
    logrotate_scripts:
      - name: "{{ item  }}"
        with_items:
          - zookeeper
          - sa
        path: "/var/log{{ item }}/{{ item }}.log "
        options:
          - daily
          - rotate 3
          - missingok
          - compress
          - notifempty
  roles:
    - log-rotation

...
```

The role is as such:

**log-rotation/tasks/main.yml**

```
---

- name: Setup logrotate.d scripts
  template:
    src: logrotate.d.j2
    dest: "{{ logrotate_conf_dir }}{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ logrotate_scripts }}"

...
```

**log-rotation/defaults/main.yml**

```
---

logrotate_conf_dir: "/etc/logrotate.d/"
logrotate_scripts: []

...
```

**log-rotation/templates/logrotate.d.j2**

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}

"{{ item.path }}" {
  {% if item.options is defined -%}
  {% for option in item.options -%}
  {{ option }}
  {% endfor -%}
  {% endif %}
  {%- if item.scripts is defined -%}
  {%- for name, script in item.scripts.iteritems() -%}
  {{ name }}
    {{ script }}
  endscript
  {% endfor -%}
  {% endif -%}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with_items` can only be used with tasks, it cannot be used when defining variables, and because of that `item` isn't defined. It also looks like that the `service` variable isn't defined as well.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! That totally makes sense as the playbook worked before I threw variables into the mix. What would be the best way to define multiple services to iterate through the logrotate template task?

Comment: set_fact inside with_items should do what you want

Comment: @MarcWKoser you could use what Matt suggested, but I would recommend that you modify your role and only pass the list of names of the services you would like to create logrotate configurations for, since as far as I can see, everything is the same except the paths to the files, which can be constructed from the name of the service.